# Control who spawns units

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, network-programming, unity3d-unet

Using unity networking service (and high level API) I am trying to have 2 clients have one building each on map, clicking on the building spawns a unit and moves it towards a target. However I am having issues understanding how I can control who can click which building. For example, "player 1" should only be able to click "building 1" to spawn units and "player 2" should only be able to click on "building 2" to spawn units.

I have setup 2 prefabs (houses) to spawn my units when clicked on.

```
public class ClickDetection : NetworkBehaviour {

    public GameObject _spawnUnit;
    public Transform _spawnPoint;

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        CmdSpawnUnit();
    }

    [Command]
    private void CmdSpawnUnit()
    {
        var spawnUnit = Instantiate(_spawnUnit, _spawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
        NetworkServer.Spawn(spawnUnit);
    }
}
```

However when I run this, only the host can click both buildings to spawn units. I can't really grasp how to let one be controlled by client and the other by the host.

Is there any easy way to identify who should be able to do what?

I don't want these to be player prefabs, I want in the end one player to be able to control several buildings (think RTS)

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am not experienced with network programming, but these observations and suggestions might bring you closer to a solution.

> Commands are sent from player objects on the client to player objects on the server. For security, Commands can only be sent from YOUR player object, so you cannot control the objects of other players.

Source: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetActions.html

Since you tell that the host can control both buildings, it would appear that the host has local player authority over them both. At least if i read the documentation correctly.

---

As per this link:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/network-spawning-of-game-objects-not-working.391315/

"commands must be run from the player objects or objects that have local player authority set to true."

Have you set it to be controlled by the local player in the network identity?

It would be helpful if you could show inspector pictures of the relevant objects.

---

Now, I haven't made a strategy game before, but I suspect you will also need to assign client authority:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkServer.SpawnWithClientAuthority.html

Which means a different spawn method.

---

Please ensure local player authoriy is assigned in the network identity of the building and please show the full inspector windows if that doesn't solve it.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Your logic seems solid here, as soon as I have time I will have a look into this and try to spawn prefabs with local authority. Thanks!